# IE's Default CSS Values

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I have a web application that I'm working on for work and its not very Firefox friendly (design was made 2 years before I started with the company). There are some CSS issues that I am having problems with and I can't use a CSS Reset because the page design is pretty much set in stone and it would cause more work then I need right now.

Does any one have a list of IE's default CSS values so I can set it in a css so this thing will be more Firefox friendly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a [CSS comparison chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(CSS)). IE actually stores the CSS settings in the ever-so-dumb-place, *the Registry*. Another issue is whether the doctype of your application is using standards mode or quirks mode.

If it's using [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode), you're in trouble. Fixing things for non-IE issues will break IE issues etc. You will go insane.

Comment: This isn't really a solution, but a solution exists.

Comment: I'm sure that 5 years later, no one really cares.

Comment: Actually, 10 years later I still have the same problem as the OP.

Answer (score 2):

TBH, I'd be surprised if IE6 actually used CSS internally for laying out the majority of HTML elements, so what you're looking for may not even exist.

The W3C have a sample stylesheet in the CSS2 spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html) which "describes the typical formatting of all HTML 4.0 ([HTML40]) elements based on extensive research into current UA practice" - copying that into a stylesheet is probably the best you'll do.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "surprised if IE6..." - the trident engine(s) comprehension of CSS is certainly baroque but it definitely listens to CSS.

Comment: I know it understands CSS. I really meant I'd be surprised if it used CSS internally, rather than some other more esoteric system.

Answer (score 2):

While I don't think I've ever seen a list posted, the IE Developer Toolbar lets you poke around the computed styles of your various elements.  Create a dummy page with each of the elements you're interested in, but no CSS, and mine out the values you need?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend approaching this problem from the other end.

Copy your current IE-only stylesheet to a global stylesheet, and put the IE stylesheet into a conditional comments block. Fix the site for Firefox using the global stylesheet, and then use the IE-only stylesheet to fix the site for IE.

Eg:

> ```
> <link href="/css/global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
> <!--[if IE ]>
>     <link href="/css/ie-only.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
> <![endif]-->
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain.
This might fix most of it.

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```