# How to get browsers native stylesheet

Tags: css, browser

Where can I get the source for a browsers native/base stylesheet?

In particular the internet explorer ones.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I locate the default style sheet for a browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214378/how-can-i-locate-the-default-style-sheet-for-a-browser). see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381558/ies-default-css-values .

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Firefox and Chrome where you can see the standard styles that were applied to its elements indenpendentemente your own CSS, IE does not. The default styles are programmed into the engine itself, but are not treated as a style sheet that can be visualized.

Answer (score 0):

You can get *almost* exact ones for different versions of Internet Explorer from here:

http://www.iecss.com/

You can pick from IE6 all the way up to IE9.

The same site also includes the user agent style sheets for some other common browsers, but it's reasonably easy to obtain them directly from these other browsers yourself.

---

<sup>There is a small problem here: if you want IE's default stylesheet *to use on your page*, you're probably doing something wrong.</sup>