# HTML Select padded with &nbsp; having issue in search

Tags: javascript, html, css, padding, html-select

I have an HTML select which has items like the below.

```
<SELECT id="mylist" size=5 >
   <OPTION Value="100">100</OPTION>
   <OPTION Value="200">200</OPTION>
   <OPTION Value="210">210</OPTION>
   <OPTION Value="211">211</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

[image]

Now if I click inside the `SELECT` and type 21 then it will select the item `210` which is the first item starts with 21. All good.

Later I wanted to add a padding to the left of the item as requested by the client. But soon I realized that padding in `SELECT` will not work in IE (at least on IE6 and IE7 which I tested)

So I added `&nbsp;&nbsp;`

```
<SELECT id="mylist" size=5 >
   <OPTION Value="100">&nbsp;&nbsp;100</OPTION>
   <OPTION Value="200">&nbsp;&nbsp;200</OPTION>
   <OPTION Value="210">&nbsp;&nbsp;210</OPTION>
   <OPTION Value="211">&nbsp;&nbsp;211</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

[image]

Now I can mimic padding.

But I lost the search option. It will not select 210 when I type 21 in IE. It works well in chrome. Please share your thoughts.

Find the sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rjXHa/)

Comment: Sometimes your IE users are just gonna have to suffer. Me personally, I punish IE 6 users and make my site looks as bad as possible for them :) but can't you wrap the select options in a span, and then use relative positioning to bump them over? ***Disclaimer: this is not a semantic solution. Unfortunately you have to do some hacking sometime with IE.

Comment: already tried that also. But IE is resisting that also :)

Comment: Do you have a live version set up anywhere?

Comment: added jsfiddle sample in the question

Comment: Especially in IE6, `select` are from outer space (as in "a select will appear above a Flash object (and ignore 'z-indexed' elements like a Lightbox); you've to disable it first. WTF??") so if you can't style them, forget the idea and make a choice between a minor design issue on deprecated browsers and a feature that powerusers use a lot (autocomplete/search in select). There I made the choice for you :)

Comment: Note: if left padding is there to show some sort of hierarchy between different options like in an hierarchical tree, then use **`optgroup`**, that's the semantics and [accessible](http://www.braillenet.org/accessibilite/referentiel-aw21-en/index.php#crit-11-8) way of doing it (see [W3C WCAG 2.0 Technique H85](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H85.html))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about wrapping it in a div:

HTML:

```
<div class="listwrapper">
    <SELECT id="mylist" size=5 >
        <OPTION Value="100">100</OPTION>
        <OPTION Value="200">200</OPTION>
        <OPTION Value="210">210</OPTION>
        <OPTION Value="211">211</OPTION>
    </SELECT>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.listwrapper
{
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
    border: solid 1px silver;
    width: 50px;
}
.listwrapper select,
.listwrapper select:active
{
    border: none 0px white;
    width: 50px;
}
​
```

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e5XUz/)

Comment: This will pad the entire listbox instead of padding only the contents.

Comment: @PraVn. That's the idea. Remove the listbox border and place it inside div. Set the border on the div instead to mimic the style of the listbox. Pad the div as if it is the listbox.

Comment: Ah, I didn't get it either: you'll see the border of the div and not the border of the select so visually (and visually only, see the width of a selected option), it'll achieve the same effect (on a multi-line select, not on a dropdown select)

Comment: @FelipeAlsacreations. Yes, this will only work on the multiline select (as asked for in the question) :)

Comment: As its the more close and simple solution, I am accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

`<style>` is an inline element hence adding a padding will not work in IE6 however with `display:block;` this can  be overcome

use

```
<style>
    #mylist
{
    padding-left:10px;
    display:block;
}
</style>​
```

Hope this helps helps. [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/cGbyP/7/)

Comment: I have already said in the question that the padding will not work with IE6 and 7

Answer (score 1):

Try to use align in CSS

```
​select { width:auto; }
option { text-align:center; }
```

This actually work. Here is [the proof in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rjXHa/43/)

Answer (score 0):

give left padding required to move options

```
#mylist
{
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EZHxv/)

Comment: @flem: Is there a reason you're bumping dozens of posts in rapid succession with 1-character edits?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the answer by Vijay is the correct way. We should always use `CSS` rather than any other.

Here is the example :-

```
<select  size="10" style="text-align:center">
<option value="1">First</option>
<option value="2">Second</option>
<option value="3">Third</option>
<option value="4">Four</option>
</select>
```

Putting the size is not mandatory .

Hope it is help full.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript code, which overrides browser search can be like this.
See the run code snippet, for example.

```js
if (!dimon) {
 var dimon = {};
}
if (!dimon.select) {
 dimon.select = {
  /**
   * Contains last typed character, and last selected option value
   * (integer). For example, { "AlternativeMobileSelectionMenu" : { "char" :
   * "s", "index" : 115 }, "AlternativeTariffSelectionMenu" : { "char" :
   * "a", "index" : 0 } }
   */
  hist : {},
  search : function(select, e) {
   // JQuery select object
   var select = $(select);
   if (!select) {
    return;
   }
   // id of HTML select, which is located under 0 index
   var sid = select[0].id;

   // dynamic HTML event
   e = e || window.event;
   var keycode = e.which || e.keyCode;
   keycode = String.fromCharCode(keycode);
   // Search should be case-insensitive
   keycode = keycode.toLowerCase();

   if (keycode < 'a' && keycode > 'z') {
    // handle only alphabetic character is typed
    return;
   }

   // Prevent default browser behavior
   if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault();
   } else {
    e.returnValue = false;
   }

   if (!this.hist[sid]) {
    this.hist[sid] = {};
   }
   var lastChar = this.hist[sid]['char'];
   if (keycode != lastChar) {
    // if a new character is typed, reset
    // last typed character
    this.hist[sid]['char'] = '';
    // and last selected option
    this.hist[sid]['index'] = -1;
   }

   // options which matches the input character
   var filteredOptions = new Array();
   // all select options
   var options = select.find("option");

   for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {

    var opt = $(options[i]);
    // Example option text
    // "  30|25   █ Magenta Mobil L mit Top-Handy"
    // "                  Sony Xperia Z2 schwarz (1,00 EUR)"
    var text = opt.text().toLowerCase();

    // Regular expression finds the first alphabetic character
    var regexp = new RegExp("[^a-z]*([a-z]{1}).*", "i");
    var result = regexp.exec(text);
    // the output will be:
    // 'm'
    // 's'
    text = result != null ? result[1] : '';

    if (opt.val() != '' && text.indexOf(keycode) == 0) {
     // add option value, if it matches
     filteredOptions.push(opt.val());
    }
   }

   var size = filteredOptions.length;
   if (size == 0) {
    return;
   }

   // Example, if we have 2 mobile devices in the list
   // Samsung Galaxy S5
   // Sony Xperia Z2
   // and type 'S', then Samsung will be selected,
   // if we type 'S' for the second time, then Sony will be selected,
   // and if we type 'S' once again, then Samsung will be selected
   // again.
   // value of the first suitable option
   var firstOpt = parseInt(filteredOptions[0]);
   // value of the last suitable option
   var lastOpt = parseInt(filteredOptions[size - 1]);
   // Last selected option value
   var lastSelected = this.hist[sid]['index'];

   if (lastSelected == -1) {
    // Character is typed for the first time
    this.hist[sid]['char'] = keycode;
    this.hist[sid]['index'] = firstOpt;
    select.val(this.hist[sid]['index']);
    select.change();

   } else if (lastSelected >= 0 && lastSelected < lastOpt) {
    // The same character is typed, just increment the option value
    this.hist[sid]['index'] = lastSelected + 1;
    select.val(this.hist[sid]['index']);
    select.change();

   } else if (lastSelected >= 0 && lastSelected == lastOpt) {
    // The same character is typed, but the last suitable option was
    // already selected before.
    // So select the first option again
    this.hist[sid]['index'] = firstOpt;
    select.val(this.hist[sid]['index']);
    select.change();
   }
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <select id="devices" size="1"
  onkeypress="dimon.select.search(this, event)">
  <option value="0">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Apple iPhone
   5s 64GB Gold (199,95 EUR)</option>
  <option value="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Samsung
   Galaxy S5 LTE+ weiß (1,00 EUR)</option>
  <option value="2">&nbsp;30|25&nbsp;█&nbsp;Sony Xperia Z2
   Tablet LTE+ (19,95 EUR)</option>
  <option value="3">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sony Xperia
   Z2 schwarz (1,00 EUR)</option>
  <option value="4">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sony Xperia
   Z2 weiß (1,00 EUR)</option>
 </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I've made this, I assume that you want something like this : [**MyFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cGbyP/)

```
<style>
    option {
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<SELECT id="mylist" size=5 >
   <OPTION Value="100">100</OPTION>
   <OPTION Value="200">200</OPTION>
   <OPTION Value="210">210</OPTION>
   <OPTION Value="211">211</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

Comment: This will not work when the values have different length as the left margin will become uneven.

Answer (score -1):

Use &nbsp to get the proper padding in IE and use key event to select the items based on key pressed.

Comment: i can select this as the answer if you can give me the javascript for this

Comment: @PraVn check my post, I went into a bit more detail on it.

Answer (score -1):

This could be part of your issue with IE6/7:

[IE's Default CSS Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381558/ies-default-css-values)

Dumb place to put default CSS values. IE8 and newer doesn't seem to have this issue.

Answer (score -1):

jQuery has solutions for this, or you can use the `onkeypress` Event to select items.

HTML

`<element onkeypress="JavaScriptCodeHere">`

JS

`object.onkeypress="JavaScriptCodeHere"`

From here, replace `JavaScriptCodeHere` with your JS script to pull the numbers based on keypress. I'm not gonna make it for you, as that is not what this site is for, but I can point you in the right direction.

`keychar` and `numcheck` might help ;)

Comment: Thanks. I wrote a function in keyup and concatenate it. Also triggered a timer to clear if the second key is not pressed in 2 seconds.